# AWS resources created in CLI not showing up in GUI

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created AWS resources around a Fargate service (and the service itself) in the AWS CLI. This includes a VPC, a subnet, a task definition, and a container repository.

When I open the GUI, I don't see any of these things. This is bad, since I need to ultimately hand this off to somebody else. I would also like to be able to use Amazon's dashboard for my services.

What do I do? Am I using AWS wrong or is this just how it works? Do I have to create resources in the GUI to be able to see them on the web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check on a different region. On your AWS console, switch regions.
Most likely, the region where you created the resources is different from your default region on the console.